# Cant refresh the page when a .load request is pending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

I'm making a website with the [Steam API](https://steamcommunity.com/dev).
I was trying it out by getting the friends list of the signed in person.

But the more friends you have, the longer it takes to load the page.
So I made the page start to load the friends as soon as the page is done loading.

If I try to refresh the page or sign out while the page is requesting the friends list, it just keeps on loading until the friend list has been fetched and only then, it refreshes the page or signs out.

How do I fix so I can refresh the page without having to wait for the request to be fuly performed.

Here is the jQuery I use to load in the PHP file:

```
$(function() {
  $('#friends').load("friendstest.php");
});
```

Please tell me if you need more information.

The [website is here](http://steamcrowd.com/homepage.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be due to a sessión write lock.

If you make the request and it takes a long time, the user session file is locked for writing, so another request can't open it for writing before the previous request release the file, and it is done at the end of the php script.

If your php script is not going to write any data in the session, you can call the session_write_close() function to release the lock (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) so you enable other request to open the session file.

So at the begining of your friendstest.php and after the session_start, you can call the session_write_close().

Comment: i added this to my code and i can now refresh the page without any problem thanks man appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the entire friends list in a single call, you can split it into multiple calls with something like:

```
upto = 0;
function loadMoreFriends() {
    $('#friends').append("friendstest.php?limit=10&start="+upto);
    upto += 10;
}
```

In this example, `upto` records how many friends have been loaded. The php would return only `10` friends and start from where the page is `upto`.

You would call this function on page load and then whenever you would like to load more friends to the page (scroll to bottom or similar).

Comment: how would i append from the php file. can you show me an example do i need to make a function in the php and then put it after append ?

Comment: I can't show you how to alter your PHP without seeing your PHP first